# HTML form that links to different pages depending on what user enters?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Is it possible to have an html that links to different websites depending on what text the user enters?  In other words, I have a simple text form where users can enter text and then hit submit.  As an example of what I'm hoping to do, is there a way to set it up so that if they enter "ABC" and hit submit it takes them to google, but if they enter "XYZ" it takes them to yahoo?

Comment: it is possible. what have you tried so far? this can be done using `javascript` or `PHP`

Comment: Yes, there's a way. With JavaScript typically. Have you tried anything?

Comment: are you implementing this just html? no js? or php?

Comment: I tried the following.  The idea is that when a user enters some text into the form, it links to a specific page.  The way I set it up was to have address as www.website.com/TEXT.html so that what they enter into the form plugs into the address, but there could be a simpler way <script type="javascript">
function goToPage(var url = '')
{
    var initial = "http://www.website.com";
    var extension = "html";

    window.location(initial+url+extension);
}
</script>

<form name="something" action="#">
Label <input type="text" name="url" value="" onchange="goToPage(this.value)">
</form>

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you need JavaScript, here's a very contrived example almost reminiscent of Web 1.0 scripts. The code sets up a listener on the textfield (keyup), and whenever it changes it calls the function changed, which then evaluates the value in the field. If it matches 'XYZ', it then sets the form's action property to be the URL where you want the form submission. In this particular case, the URL to will be something that doesn't exist. Now of course this is not a complete solution and you'll have to spend a bit of time getting the handler to work correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" id="mytext" onkeyup="changed()">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function changed()
    {
        var v = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
        if("XYZ" === v)
        {
            var action = "http://www.foobar.nothing/" + v;
            document.getElementById('myform').action = action;
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```